# how to parse 3 level nested array using newtonsoft json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following json which is in geojson format, and Id like to be able to parse this into a nested list in c#:

`public IList<IList<IList<double>>> Coordinates { get; set; }`

```
"coordinates": [
    [
        [-3.213338431720785, 55.940382588499197],
        [-3.213340490487523, 55.940381867350276],
        [-3.213340490487523, 55.940381867350276],
        [-3.213814166228732, 55.940215021175085],
        [-3.21413960035129, 55.940100842843712]
    ]
]
```

I have tried the following but I get an exception:

```
    var node = jsonProperties["geometry"]["coordinates"].Values();
    var coordinates = node.Select(x=>x.Value<List<double>>());
```

Exception detail:

> Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.

Comment: why you don't use node variable ? Where is d variable comes from?

Comment: @Anjmao sorry that was a typo

Comment: It looks like you need to reference the first element of "coordinates" array, not the coordinates array itself.  Did you try something like `var node = jsonProperties["geometry"]["coordinates"][0].Values();` (unsure of exact syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deserialize using `newtonsoft`. Create `Foo` class with a `coordinates` property, inclose the JSON script with curly brackets to denote it as an object then call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(Json)`.

```
private class Foo
{
     public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

 var json = @"{
                 coordinates: [
                                [
                                    [-3.213338431720785, 55.940382588499197],
                                    [-3.213340490487523, 55.940381867350276],
                                    [-3.213340490487523, 55.940381867350276],
                                    [-3.213814166228732, 55.940215021175085],
                                    [-3.21413960035129, 55.940100842843712]
                                ]
                            ]
                    }";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
```

Comment: You can also have proper C# PascalCase naming by setting `ContractResolver` property to `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` instance (second parameter)

Answer (score 1):

May not be exactly what you want but using dynamic type I could access the values. For example this sample code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sampleJson = @"{ ""coordinates"": [
            [
                [-3.213338431720785, 55.940382588499197],
                [-3.213340490487523, 55.940381867350276],
                [-3.213340490487523, 55.940381867350276],
                [-3.213814166228732, 55.940215021175085],
                [-3.21413960035129, 55.940100842843712]
            ]
        ]}";

        dynamic d = JObject.Parse(sampleJson);

        Console.WriteLine(d.coordinates[0].Count);
        foreach (var coord in d.coordinates[0])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", coord[0], coord[1]);
        }

   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

displays the following:

```
5
-3.21333843172079, 55.9403825884992
-3.21334049048752, 55.9403818673503
-3.21334049048752, 55.9403818673503
-3.21381416622873, 55.9402150211751
-3.21413960035129, 55.9401008428437
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to parse them into something more suitable like `List<Tuple<double, double>>` though there is also solution for nested lists. Please check my inline comments:

```
const string json = @"
    { 
        ""coordinates"": 
        [
            [
                [-3.213338431720785, 55.940382588499197],
                [-3.213340490487523, 55.940381867350276],
                [-3.213340490487523, 55.940381867350276],
                [-3.213814166228732, 55.940215021175085],
                [-3.21413960035129, 55.940100842843712]
            ]
        ]
    }";

var jsObject = JObject.Parse(json);
/*
 * 1. Read property "coordinates" of your root object
 * 2. Take first element of array under "coordinates"
 * 3. Select each pair-array and parse their values as doubles
 * 4. Make a list of it
 */
var result = jsObject["coordinates"]
                .First()
                .Select(pair => new Tuple<double, double> (
                        pair[0].Value<double>(), 
                        pair[1].Value<double>()
                    )
                ).ToList();
```

And for `List<List<List<double>>>` please see @YTAM answer.